# Is there something called **swat** bread bowls?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=102) (a video link with a time stamp)

> we really don't wanna have **swat** bread bowls

which **swat** does not make any sense here.

what is she talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (auto-generated) CC says "flat bread bowls", and I'd agree with that:

[image]

They also say they want "tall bread bowls", so "flat" seems likely, contrasting with "tall".

Comment: the cc does not fit what I listened, although makes more sense.

Comment: @zghqh it sounds like "fwat" to me, perhaps that's how they pronounce it, or they  mispronounced it, or there was a glitch in the recording ....

Comment: @zghqh I can only agree with this answer - I hear a clear “flat”. Maybe it’s the accent?

Comment: Yep, I listened to it a few more times with my headphones on, and now I'm certain it's a "flat".

Comment: @Stephie in terms of semantic or the mean of sentence, it could be a "flat". Alghough I didn't hear a clear “flat”. Are you sure you heard a clear “flat”?